# Convert Character column value to binary value in data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a class column in my data frame which carries the value "Bad" & "Good". I want to replace these string into 0 & 1 respectively.

I tried the following:

```
 x = c("Bad", "Good", "Bad", "Bad", "Good")

factor(x)

factor(x, c(0, 1))
```

but, it converts the value in the dataset to `NA`

```
factor(x, c(0, 1))

[1] <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>`
Levels: 0 1`
```

Comment: `as.integer(x=="Good")` . Yours doesnt work as `factor` looks for levels 0/ 1 which arent there. So be explicit `factor(x, levels=c("Bad", "Good"), labels=c(0, 1))`

Comment: It worked. Thanks :)

Answer (score 7):

A convenient tidyverse approach would be to use dplyr's `recode` function.

```
df <- data.frame(x = c("Bad", "Good", "Bad", "Bad", "Good"))
df$x <- as.factor(df$x)

library(tidyverse)
df <- df %>% 
    mutate(x = recode(x, 
                      "Bad" = "0", 
                      "Good" = "1"))
```

That's assuming you want to keep it as a factor column. If you'd rather it be a numeric vector you'd simply add a second mutate call to convert it to numeric... EDIT: being careful to convert the values as numbers, not the underlying level codes.

```
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(x = recode(x, 
                    "Bad" = "0", 
                    "Good" = "1")) %>% 
  mutate(x = as.numeric(levels(x))[x])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a named vector to map the text strings to numeric values.

```
df <- data.frame( x = c("Bad", "Good", "Bad", "Bad", "Good"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

lookup <- c("Bad" = 0, "Good" = 1)

df$new_x <- lookup[df$x]
```

Result

```
df
     x new_x
1  Bad     0
2 Good     1
3  Bad     0
4  Bad     0
5 Good     1


# showing type info
str(df)
'data.frame':   5 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ x    : chr  "Bad" "Good" "Bad" "Bad" ...
 $ new_x: num  0 1 0 0 1
```